# How to use only next and previous button in pagination in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pagination

Hello i am having php code for pagination where page number  displaying i want to use only

Next and Previous Button  How can i achieve this

Here is my code

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
  mysql_select_db('Helixcrm', $con);

  $per_page = 15; 
  $select_table = "select * from tbl_site_configs";
  $variable = mysql_query($select_table);
  $count = mysql_num_rows($variable);
  $pages = ceil($count/$per_page)    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Qjuery pagination with loading effect using PHP and MySql</title>

        //Scripts
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            function Display_Load() {
                $("#load").fadeIn(1000, 0);
                $("#load").html("<img src='load.gif' />");
            }

            function Hide_Load() {
                $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
            };

            $("#paginate li:first").not('.page').css({
                'color': '#FF0084'
            }).css({
                'border': 'none'
            });
            Display_Load();
            $("#content").load("pagination.php?page=1", Hide_Load());

            <? php $page; ?>

            $("#paginate li").not('.page').click(function() {
                Display_Load();
                $("#paginate li").css({
                    'border': 'solid #193d81 1px'
                }).css({
                    'color': '#0063DC'
                }).removeClass("active");
                $(this).css({
                    'color': '#FF0084'
                }).css({
                    'border': 'none'
                }).addClass("active");
                var pageNum = this.id;
                $("#content").load("pagination.php?page=" + pageNum, Hide_Load());

            });

            $("#paginate li.page").click(function() {
                var page = $(this).attr("data-value");
                if (page == "prev") {
                    var index = $("#paginate li.active").index();
                    if (index > 1) {
                        $("#paginate li.active").prev().trigger("click");
                    } else {
                        $("#paginate li.active").trigger("click");
                    }
                } else {
                    var index = $("#paginate li.active").index();
                    if (index < $("#paginate li").length - 2) {
                        $("#paginate li.active").next().trigger("click");
                    } else {
                        $("#paginate li.active").trigger("click");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            #load { 
                width:30px;
                padding-top:50px;
                border:0px green dashed;
                margin:0 auto;
            }
            #paginate {
                text-align:center;
                border:0px green solid;
                width:500px;
                margin:0 auto;
            }
            .link {
                width:800px; 
                margin:0 auto; 
                border:0px green solid;
            }

            li{ 
                list-style: none; 
                float: left;
                margin-right: 16px; 
                padding:5px; 
                border:solid 1px #193d81;
                color:#0063DC; 
            }
            li:hover { 
                color:#FF0084; 
                cursor: pointer; 
            }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content" ></div>
    <div class="link" align="center">
        <ul id="paginate">
           <li id="" class="page" data-value="prev">Prev</li>
           <?php 
                for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++) {
                    echo '<li id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</li>';
                }  
            ?>
            <li id="" class="page" data-value="next">Next</li>
         </ul>   
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"> </div>
    <div id="load" align="center" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me to short out my problem

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: i tried  to remove echo

Comment: @sheetalsharma well that should do it - what happened when you tried that

Comment: then number removed but next and previous but stop working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im guessing removing the echo wont work because then you have no data elements which have `active` bound to them.

Try making a `.hidden` class in your css to hide each of your echoed li elements, that way they can still have `active` bound to them, but they won't be visible on the DOM

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Your markup would then look something like this

```
<li class='next'><li>

    <li id="1" class="hidden active">1</li>
    <li id="2" class="hidden">2</li>
    <li id="3" class="hidden">3</li>

<li class='prev'><li>
```

Comment: how can i hidden active only page number 1

Comment: In your JavaScript where you apply active, apply the hidden class too if you only want to apply hidden to the current index. Or if you only want to show the active page then remove the hidden class from the active index and apply hidden to all other indexs in your JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

If you can't solve your issue, I'd recommend that you don't really need javascript for pagination, it can be achieved purely through PHP (Which is actually really simple to do), I've done it myself for one of my websites using this code example..

http://www.developphp.com/page.php?id=289

Go ahead and check it out if you can't solve this problem out,

Also he produced a video explaining which sections you need to change, and going through what each part of the code does/means:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8xYGnEOXYc

Comment: give the title of his page begins `"Qjuery pagination with loading effect..."` i doubt this is much help

Comment: @user574632 What title of what page?

Comment: The html page in his question

Comment: His question is 'How to use only next and previous button in pagination in php'

Comment: I don't really see why that matters, I've clearly stated in my answer as an alternative to not using js, It produces actually what he is looking for (it also hides the back and next buttons if they are not needed which I believe he wants), I didn't come on here for an argument/debate over it, I'm just trying to provide the user with a solution to the problem.